# Display specific xml data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have created a `WinForm` in C#, now I want to show the selected data of my XML file to show in `DataGridView`.  I found some links that helped with showing the selected elements in the `DataGridView` but it's not showing as it should be.

Following is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Vehicle>
    <Number_Plate>PHZ-888</Number_Plate>
    <Make>Honda</Make>
    <Model>City</Model>
    <Year>2008</Year>
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle>
    <Number_Plate>VGQ-141</Number_Plate>
    <Make>Suzuki</Make>
    <Model>Mehran</Model>
    <Year>2001</Year>
  </Vehicle>
  <Vehicle>
    <Number_Plate>VZH-403</Number_Plate>
    <Make>Audi</Make>
    <Model>A7</Model>
    <Year>2008</Year>
  </Vehicle>

  <Vehicle>
    <Number_Plate>BCH-184</Number_Plate>
    <Make>Honda</Make>
    <Model>Accord CL9</Model>
    <Year>2007</Year>
  </Vehicle>
</root>
```

Here is the query I'm trying to use to get specific elements:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("vehicle20.xml");

var query = from key in xdoc.Descendants("Vehicle")
            where key != null && (key.Element("Make").Value == makelist)
            select key.Value;
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

`makelist` is how I am passing the car model to search for, such as "Honda".

And After querying it shows this:

[image]

But I want to display with all the descendants of specified vehicle elements, like for Audi to show only Audi data, this way:

[image]

Comment: I think you want to use "select key" instead of "select key.Value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is expected, because your are selecting `Key.value`. If you want to get the desired display, you should wrap your result in an object:

```
var query = from key in xdoc.Descendants("Vehicle")
          where key != null && (key.Element("Make").Value == "Honda")
          select new
          {
             Make = key.Element("Make").Value,
             Model = key.Element("Model").Value
          };
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can load xml data to a `DataSet` and show it in `DataGridView` simply this way:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("path to the xml file");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //ds.Tables[Vehicle]
```

Then to filter data and show some specific rows, you can apply filter this way:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "Make='Honda'";
```